# How to add the same http://localhost:9080 as a 'BaseUrls' in "preview and live" target in topology manger

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, dxa-java, topology-manager, microservices

How to add the same http://localhost:9080 as a 'BaseUrls' in "preview and live" target in topology manger?

I can add the above base URL in preview and it's working fine when I try to add in Live. it's throwing this exception:

```
Set-TtmWebsite -id Website826L -BaseUrls http://localhost:9080
Set-TtmWebsite : Invalid value for property 'BaseUrls'. The base URL 'http://localhost:9080' is already used as base URL in another website with Id 'Website826P'
```

Comment: This is by design. is there a reason you want to use the same base url for preview and live?

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes. My development team size is 10. I do not want to change/update the developer IP(it's dynamic one, will be changing an every day) very often to point the different target on daily basis.

Comment: I understand that you may want to use a localhost url so that it doesn’t change (unlike the machine IP address). But, why do Preview and Live need to be the same URL? Can’t these just be on different ports?

Comment: thanks. We can update the different port but I do not want to change the port all developers since we have many app running(not only tridion based app) in different port on local server. It's really pain some time the server throws exception as it's already used. every time we have to stop other app on same or different server (think about WebSphere) used the same port & used service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as you shouldn’t be able to use the same url for two sites (within Topology Manager).

You’re going to have to either:

1. Specify a different port
2. Use a different hosts name (and probably update your hosts file /DNS), or
3. Use the machine name / machine IP Address (e.g. http://192.168.0.22:9080)
4. Try to use http://127.0.0.1:9080

However, I’m not sure why you’d want to use the same URL for Staging and Live, as this would render the Tridion “View on Site” functionality useless.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Jonathan. if it's big size of development team to switch their host or port mapping very often to point dev target. it's really pain.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You need to choose between one of these options. I'd go with having your devs map names in their hosts files. They shouldn't need to do it often.